# How to create corpid-2 service and bind it to my app. Invalid UAA client config

Tags: swisscomdev

I would like to create a corpid-2 service to be able to allow certain person to a simple web app in python.
I'm facing the problem about some parameters that needs to be given. 
I am not able to find these parameters in the swisscom documentation https://coders.swisscom.com/docs/browse/iAPC/services/corproot-identity-v2

[EDIT]
More Swisscom internal question. I will continue the discussion on internal tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to provide the required `-c` parameters. You can find an example of it in the docs:

https://coders.swisscom.com/docs/browse/iAPC/services/corproot-identity-v2/back-end.html

or

https://coders.swisscom.com/docs/browse/iAPC/services/corproot-identity-v2/client.html

Depending on your use case.

Please be aware that the Stackoverflow channel is meant for public information only - Swisscom internal questions like corpid should not land here; I suggest to delete the question or ask it again on Askthebrain, I'll happily answer there as well.

Comment: thank you a lot. yesterday the two links you gave me were not working. I will continue de discussion on askthebrain if needed. P.S. i cannot delete my question.